# How to measure frequency of sine wave?

Tags: microcontroller, measurement, frequency-measurement

How to measure frequency of sine wave using pic microcontroller? I found the article on this website
http://microcontrollerslab.com/sine-wave-frequency-measurement-using-pic/
But I didn't understand code. Anyone can help me to understand code on this website?

Comment: You need to tell us a little more about your application. What frequency is the signal? What voltage range? How are you sampling it, and what are your requirements for accuracy etc?

Comment: I've looked at the code, it seems to me it won't work well but I might be wrong. What part is not clear to you?

Comment: Might I recommend 2 measurements within 1 microsecond to approximate the gradient? The frequency is just the time between sign changes in the gradient. It'd be rather more accurate.

Comment: You need to tell us which part of it you don't understand.  The diagram and the code are fairly clear if you understand the language, the circuitry, and the system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the key element of the frequency measurement code:

```
TMR0=0; // clear TMR0
Delay_ms(1000); // Delay 1 Sec
...
Display_Freq(TMR0/2); // divide by 2
```

The author is using the TMR0 timer/counter to count the zero-crossing events of the input signal. (The article uses a transformer to step down 220VACrms 50Hz mains line frequency to 9VACrms, then uses a full bridge rectifier and a resistive divider to generate the zero-crossing event signal. I'm not sure how they intended to test this circuit.)

After running the counter for 1 second, the value in the counter is equal to double the frequency, because each full-wave rectified cycle has two pulses.

The rest of the code in `Display_Freq(f)` is just user interface code, to convert the numerical frequency into characters to display on the LCD.

Comment: This answer is good but I don't like the design. There's no 'anti bounce', and if used as a periodmeter that 'zero crossing detection' circuit will show what it's really worth. Dr Coconut suggestion above, implement a gradient change detector, guarantees much more precision. The ADC is needed of course but it does not seem to me that the micro is doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question, here is another way to get a measurement by the more general method of curve fitting.

We start by using a generic sine equation which includes amplitude `a`, phase `c` and frequency `b` and time `x`.
$$
g(x) = a \cdot sin(b \cdot x + c) 
$$
Assuming harmonics and other disturbances being normal distributed, we can do standard least-square fitting. Hence, we can define a loss function
$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i -  g(x_i))^2 
$$ with `y_i` being the measured amplitude at time `i`.

By finding the minimum of `L` we can read the frequency by looking at `b/(2*pi)`.
Minimizing `L` can be done by following the steepest descent direction of the gradient at which it becomes zero.
$$
\nabla L(a,b,c) = \mathbf{0}
$$
This leads to the system
$$
\nabla L(a,b,c) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial b} \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
(y_i - g(x)) \cdot sin(b\cdot x_i+c) \\
(y_i - g(x)) \cdot a \cdot x_i \cdot cos(b\cdot x_i+c)\\
(y_i - g(x)) \cdot a \cdot cos(b\cdot x_i+c)
\end{pmatrix}
$$.

The system can be solved by following the steepest descent direction of the gradient which leads to updates of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{new}\\
b_{new}\\
c_{new}
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{old}\\
b_{old}\\
c_{old}
\end{pmatrix} - \alpha \cdot \nabla L(a_{old},b_{old},c_{old})
$$ with `\alpha` a small number beeing the learning rate/stepsize.

If amplitude or phase is known the respective equations can be replaced by constants, thus simplifying the system.

Comment: Will this method give an erroneous answer (local minima) if the initial guess for `a,b,c` are far off from the true value ? Gradient descent, finds only the local minima right ? If initial guess for `b` is far off another sinusoid at an *alias* frequency can also minimise the cost function; right ?